# Not working Translations with Environments in Yii2

Tags: php, yii, yii2

I have set `3 environments`.

My app needs to load different sets of translations because each env is different.

I have the `RO`, `HU`, `DE` languages.

I am trying to set the translations, but it does not work.

in frontend/config main.php i have:

`'sourceLanguage' => 'en',
    'language' => 'en',`

in the `frontend/web/index.php` i have:

`defined('YII_ENV') or define('YII_ENV', 'dev_ro');`

also, i am merging the config array:

`(file_exists(__DIR__ . '/../../environments/' . YII_ENV . '/common/config/main-local.php') ? require(__DIR__ . '/../../environments/' . YII_ENV . '/common/config/main-local.php') : [])`

now, in `environments/dev_ro/common/config/`, in `components` i have:

```
'i18n' => [
            'translations' => [
                'companie' => [
                    'class' => 'yii\i18n\PhpMessageSource',
                    'basePath' => '@app/messages',
                    'sourceLanguage' => 'en',
                    'fileMap' => [
                        'companie' => 'companie.php',
                    ],
                ],
            ],
        ],
```

in the `Companie` model i have:

```
'nume' => Yii::t('companie', 'Name'),
```

this is the movie, with my thing:

[movie](http://screencast.com/t/WrCm20PoCbp)

Comment: 'basePath' => '@app/messages', @app will be different in frontend/backend, where are your messages files?

Comment: this does not work either; i will create a movie

Comment: edited answer, alias is: Yii::setAlias('@common', dirname(__DIR__));

Comment: this is not working either

Comment: still same error or not traslated?

Comment: in movie http://monosnap.com/image/TpefWQW8xiZy5sr3RJNyY1KZl7miH9 there is basePath=>'@app/messages', did you change it?

Comment: test it like this \Yii::$app->language = 'ru';echo Yii::t('companie', 'Name');exit;

Comment: something is wrong with envs and translations; to complicated; translations should be in only 1 place, separated by files, like in yii 1; tired of trying to translate

Comment: also you got sourceLanguage 'ro' and folder 'ro' - so you are going to translate from romanian to romanian. Set 'sourceLanguage'=>'en'.

Comment: i did try that; it does not work; i need a full example with this thing; i am fully messed up right now; i will not use yii translations for now;

Comment: i updated answer, there is full example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in app*, because it's not app* category, this works:

```
    'i18n' => [
        'translations' => [
            '*' => [
                'class' => 'yii\i18n\PhpMessageSource',
                'fileMap' => [
                    'companie' => 'companie.php',
                ],
            ],
        ],
    ],
```

Or if you want write `'companie*' =>`

If it is still not working, you did set incorrect path to translate files. By default it must be `BasePath/messages/LanguageID/CategoryName.php`.

If you want to use one file in backend and frontend you should create for example common alias in common config (advanced yii application) and set this alias in i18n config. This is full example:

Common config:

```
Yii::setAlias('@common', dirname(__DIR__));
return [
    'language' => 'ru',
    'sourceLanguage' => 'ru',
    'components' => [
    'i18n' => [
        'translations' => [
            '*' => [
                'class' => 'yii\i18n\PhpMessageSource',
                'basePath' => '@common/messages',
                'fileMap' => [
                    'companie' => 'companie.php',
                ],
  ....
```

In traslate file /common/messages/en-US/companie.php

```
<?php
return [
    'string in russian' => 'string in english'
];
```

Check translate using this code:

```
\Yii::$app->language = 'en-US';
echo \Yii::t('companie', 'string in russian');
```

Comment: it does not work for me; some questions: does app stand for frontend or backend or any allias?and does fileMap need a path to the file?

Comment: @IonutFlaviusPogacian i think its because of wrong path, path should be frontend/messages/LanguageID/companie.php. If you want to use one file set 'basePath' => '@frontent/messages', where frontent is common alias

Comment: pls write as answer your solution; i cant figure out what you are saying

Comment: language and source language should have different values; and my pc needed a restart in order to load new config; dkw that happened

Answer (score 0):

You can also try to replace dash with underscore in language code and folder name:

```
en-US >> en_US
```

Works for me.