# How to save message on message table and source_message table

Tags: translation, yii2, multiple-languages

In yii1, I usualy call with `Yii:t("global","This is text demo")`.

When I change languages and it will be save into message and source_message table.
After I can manage and translate it from web page.

With yii2, I read more example, but almost they guide to translate from file.
Like this example : [Not working Translations with Environments in Yii2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23247655/not-working-translations-with-environments-in-yii2) .

I don't know how to config for it can save into database like yii1.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you reading [Internationalization](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-tutorial-i18n.html) section of official documentation, especially [Message translation](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-tutorial-i18n.html#message-translation) paragraph.

So in Yii 2 you also have possibility to use database for that purpose.

[yii\i18n\DbMessageSource](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-i18n-dbmessagesource.html) class is responsible for this logic.